# Which chain support/doesn't support

Tags: eip-1559

I have a problem here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72616326/why-i-cannot-send-ftm-with-this-simple-code?noredirect=1#comment128290320_72616326

I think the problem is that I tried to use Fee1559Suggestions for chains that don't support it.

Do we have list of chains that support that vs chains that do not?

Also I tried to look on the web but the result is too confusing. If you can give short explanation of what EIP-1559 and why it's not implemented on every chain, it'll be great too.

Comment: Most main alternative L1 chains were forked / started before EIP-1559 was implemented on Ethereum, and those alternative chains simply haven't implemented that (yet). No idea which chains have it, but probably not many. You can search for EIP-1559 explanations around here for example, plenty of resources available.

Comment: Ah. And EIP-1559 won't be there for most fork? Or will it be there?